# Undefined function reg_open_key() in PHP 7.0

Tags: php

I'm trying to access windows registry but it shows an error. Any suggestions?

I am using `PHP 7.0`.

```
<?php
    // device instance ID
    $id = "0060E049DF74EC311000711F";


    $keyConst = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE';
    $key = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR\Enum";

    if (!($reg = reg_open_key($keyConst, $key))) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot access registry.");
    }

    $found = false;
    $numDevices = reg_get_value($reg, "Count");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDevices; $i++) {
        $value = reg_get_value($reg, $i);
        if (strpos($val, $id) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }    
    reg_close_key($reg);

    echo "USB drive dongle ", ($found) ? "found" : "not found";

?>
```

Comment: I don't see `reg_open_key()` in the php docs - https://secure.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=reg_open_key&scope=quickref

Comment: plz visit this link https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vUu7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=reg_open_key()+php&source=bl&ots=4_lpsxh2id&sig=WfRj8YSN3zLhknRg2aqNNHlE3dc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj7Ler2tfRAhXMsY8KHSJeBmMQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=reg_open_key()%20php&f=false

Comment: this function has been mentioned there

Comment: i think it is now removed/changed in php 7.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the [win32std](https://pecl.php.net/package/win32std) package first.

Comment: thnx! but any guidance how to install it?

Comment: That is really a separate issue. Please search on google and stackoverflow for how to install a PHP package from PECL and ask a different question if you're stuck.

Comment: Sir can you please help me installing Win32std dll file?